# A query to find or create relationship and increment its count property by one

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I want to count "the number of times a node is connected to another node".

It seemed a bad idea to have multiple redundant relationships between the two same nodes, so I thought I should use a single relationship with a "count" property for this purpose.

But how to update those relationships and increment the property "count"?

Neo4j doesn't have any auto-increment function for properties (according to what I read).

As an alternative, I wanted to MATCH the existing relationship (if it exists), and then update its count property, in Python, but nothing seems to work.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def create_or_increment_relationship(tx, start_node_label, start_node_property, new_node_label, new_node_property, relationship_type):

    return tx.run(

        "MATCH (s) WHERE (s.label = $start_node_label AND s.name = $start_node_property) \n \
        CALL apoc.merge.node($new_node_label, {name: $new_node_property}) \n \
        MATCH (s)-[r:$relationship_type]->(n) \n \
        CALL apoc.merge.relationship(s, $relationship_type, r.count+1, n);",

        start_node_label=start_node_label,
        start_node_property=start_node_property,
        new_node_label=new_node_label,
        new_node_property=new_node_property,
        relationship_type=relationship_type,

    ).single().value()
```

The query above (in green) has 4 lines:

- find the start_node (s, which should already exist)
- find or create the new_node (n, which sometimes doesn't exist)
- find the relationship between them (r, which doesn't exist if n doesn't exist)
- if it exists, increment its "count" property by one, else set it to one (r.count)

I understand that I would also need to use APOC to MATCH an existing relationship based on a label established at runtime (dynamic label, i.e. a Python variable). (That's the third line in the query part of this code.)

However I wasn't able to find any example of such a query, or an apoc function that matches relationships on criteria.

---

UPDATE: so apparently a way to MATCH relationships in APOC is to use apoc.merge.relationship as described in this post https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/2674:

> In the second example, I'm using apoc.merge.node to MATCH the start and end nodes without actually creating or changing them. My assumption is though, that Neo4j still write-locks these nodes which affects the performance and would hinder optimisations such as parallelisation via apoc.periodic.iterate due to deadlocks on the same node.

... To the maintainers of APOC: I do agree it would be nice if there was a apoc.match.relationship (or node) function. It would be nice I think for ease of use / understanding / clarity of the API; and this poster also says that a dedicated implementation could bring performance benefits in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to consider:

1. The statement below DOES NOT work when using a parameterized query.  So your query is not returning data after this statement. Thus, no relationship will be created in the last line

> MATCH (s)-[r:$relationship_type]->(n)

Fix: You need to do a string replace using python when the variable is a relationship type.

2. apoc.merge.relationship will not create a relationship if the previous MATCH does NOT return a row. The query will simply end without running the last apoc statement.

Fix: use a MERGE on CREATE on MATCH instead

3. Besides there are typo errors on your query so I suggest you debug the cypher query by copying the actual statement you generated then run it in neo4j console.

Fix: look at line #1 and line #2 of my query.

Below is a working snippet of code that you can use.

```
from neo4j import GraphDatabase 

uri="bolt://localhost:7687"
user="neo4j"
password="<awesome_psw>"

driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=(user, password))
session = driver.session()

start_node_label = 'Person'
start_node_property = 'user' 
new_node_label = 'NewPerson'
new_node_property = 'newuser'
relationship_type = 'RELATED_TO'

cypher = "MATCH (s) WHERE $start_node_label in labels(s) AND s.name = $start_node_property \n \
          CALL apoc.merge.node([$new_node_label], {{name: $new_node_property}}) YIELD node as n \n \
          MERGE (s)-[r:{relationship_type}]->(n) \n \
             ON CREATE set r.count = 1  \n \
             ON MATCH set r.count = r.count + 1 \n \
          RETURN r;"
query  = cypher.format(relationship_type = relationship_type)
result = session.run(query,
        start_node_label=start_node_label,
        start_node_property=start_node_property,
        new_node_label=new_node_label,
        new_node_property=new_node_property,
        relationship_type=relationship_type)
d = result.single().value() 
print(d)
```

Sample result:

```
<Relationship id=7 nodes=(<Node id=8 labels=frozenset() properties={}>, <Node id=7 labels=frozenset() properties={}>) type='HAS' properties={'count': 1}>
```

Comment: Yes amazing. Thank you. It works perfectly -- I didn't even change a single character in your cypher query :)

Yes indeed my first MATCH didn't return anything, I realized later; that's probably what made it hard to debug at first. I wanted to use APOC to replace MATCH but you instead inserted the variable values manually in the cypher -- great! 

Follow up question: why use APOC if you can instead insert (or string replace) variables values in your cypher query? (Sorry if this is a very basic / newby question). I might make a new post for this is you think it's worth it.

Comment: No worries, we are all learning from one another. Using APOC for your case is optional, you can use variables (as parameters) to create nodes as you suggested. Using APOC makes your code looks simpler and easier to read. IMHO.